# What are options for upgrading signing key for Play Store and self-published universal APK?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

I am one of the maintainers of an Android application that has been in development since 2008. We currently manage our own release key and we would like to start using a new, more secure key. Our users generally install from the Play Store but some require universal APKs which we would like to continue publishing. We would like these to be compatible with Play Store installs/updates and we would like to publish one per version (i.e. not two signed with new and old keys). Our app is currently signed using the [v1 and v2 schemes](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning).

As I understand it, we have the following options:

1. Continue managing our own keys. Generate a new, modern key. Create a rotation lineage between the two keys. When releasing, sign with the old key, the new key, and the lineage file using [the v3 scheme](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v3). Upload that to both the Play Store and as the self-published universal APK.
2. Opt into App Signing and upload the older key. [Request a key upgrade for new installs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?rd=1#upgrade&zippy=%2Crequest-a-key-upgrade-for-new-installs-not-suitable-for-all-apps) (which may or may not be granted). Generate a new, modern key locally. Upload that key as the updated key. From the Play Store, that new key will be used for new installs, the older key will be used for existing installs. For the self-published universal APK, we can create a rotation lineage between the two keys and sign with that.
3. Opt into App Signing and upload the older key. [Upgrade signing key for Android 13+](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?visit_id=638089771974131141-3578058400&rd=1#upgrade&zippy=%2Crequest-a-key-upgrade-for-all-installs-on-android-t-api-level-and-above-recommended). Generate a new, modern key locally. Upload that key as the updated key. From the Play Store, Android 13+ devices will get installs and updates signed with the new key, all others will get installs and updates signed with the old key. From the self-published universal APK, we can create a rotation lineage between the two keys and sign with that.

In an ideal world, we could enroll in App Signing, let Google manage the signing and download a single universal APK to share. Both paths would work for upgrading existing installs (old key) on all Android versions (we support down to Android 5.1). My understanding is that this is not possible because App Signing does not use the v3 signing scheme or any other standard for establishing a relationship between old and new key. The latest information I can find on this is in a [May 2020 dev rel article on App Signing](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/answers-to-common-questions-about-app-signing-by-google-play-b28fef836af0):

> the current key upgrade process does not take advantage of the key rotation feature introduced in Android 9 (Pie) and above. We are currently investigating support for key rotation using app signing v3 for devices on these OS versions and will let the developer community know once it’s ready in a separate announcement.

I can find no related announcement or documentation.

**Have I correctly understood our options? Is there any reason not to continue managing keys and using the v3 scheme to rotate on Android 9 and above?**

**EDIT**: I previously asked what "upgrade signing key for Android 13+" does differently from "request a key upgrade for new installs"?
and found a partial answer in [Android 13 release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/summary):

> “APK Signature Scheme v3.1 allows apps to support original and rotated signers in a single APK and also supports SDK version targeting.”

With more [in the overview](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features#apk-signature-scheme). My understanding is that App Signing DOES use key rotation now but only with the v3.1 scheme which is only supported in Android 13+. However, that would be inconsistent with [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?rd=1#upgrade&zippy=%2Cimportant-considerations-before-requesting-a-key-upgrade) which says

> Note: Requesting an app signing key upgrade for new installs in Play Console is unrelated to key rotation introduced in APK signature scheme v3 for Android P and above.

Answer (score 2):

Background: I'm part of the team responsible for Google Play App Signing.

Regarding the available options for upgrading the signing key:

> 1. Continue managing our own keys. Generate a new, modern key. Create a rotation lineage between the two keys. When releasing, sign with the old key, the new key, and the lineage file using the v3 scheme. Upload that to both the Play Store and as the self-published universal APK.

Using rotation lineages on APKs directly is not supported in Play.

> 2. Opt into App Signing and upload the older key. Request a key upgrade for new installs (which may or may not be granted). Generate a new, modern key locally. Upload that key as the updated key. From the Play Store, that new key will be used for new installs, the older key will be used for existing installs. For the self-published universal APK, we can create a rotation lineage between the two keys and sign with that.

Requesting a key upgrade for new installs will be granted (it's also a self-service) -- but it's not the recommended approach. Also please note that this case of key upgrade works on the basis that both keys (the old and new one) are not related to each other. In other words, the new key would be solely used for new installs and their updates, and the old key would be solely used for existing installs and their updates. For the self-published universal APK, if it gets signed with a rotation lineage, updates for the APKs that got signed with the new key wouldn't work (at least for pre-Android P (9) where key rotation is not supported).

> 3. Opt into App Signing and upload the older key. Upgrade signing key for Android 13+. Generate a new, modern key locally. Upload that key as the updated key. From the Play Store, Android 13+ devices will get installs and updates signed with the new key, all others will get installs and updates signed with the old key. From the self-published universal APK, we can create a rotation lineage between the two keys and sign with that.

This is the **recommended** approach for upgrading the signing key in Play ([ref](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#upgrade&zippy=request-a-key-upgrade-for-all-installs-on-android-t-api-level-and-above-recommended)). In this approach, the [APK signature scheme V3.1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features#apk-signature-scheme) is utilized, in which a rotation lineage is created to establish a relationship between old and new key. For the self-published universal APK, it would have a compatible signature if it gets signed with a rotation lineage between the old and new key using APK signature scheme **V3.1**.

For the note in [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#upgrade&zippy=important-considerations-before-requesting-a-key-upgrade) that you referenced:

> > Note: Requesting an app signing key upgrade for new installs in Play Console is unrelated to key rotation introduced in APK signature scheme v3 for Android P and above.

It refers to the [app signing key upgrade for new installs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#upgrade&zippy=request-a-key-upgrade-for-new-installs-not-suitable-for-all-apps) approach (that is option #2 in the options you stated).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. It would be helpful in evaluating next steps to understand more of the why. Why is requesting a key upgrade for new installs not recommended? It seems like more users would get the more secure key and the old key would fade away over time. Why isn’t rotation with v3 or v3.1 supported for Play Store APK uploads?

Comment: (sorry I had to trim my answers to fit the comment limit)

`> Why is requesting a key upgrade for new installs not recommended?`

With 2 separate keys, each app version signed with one key wouldn't be update-compatible with an app version signed with the other key (the app needs to be uninstalled and re-installed to get the new key). This is not the case for the recommended option (which is the Android platform-supported mechanism for signing key rotation), where the key gets automatically changed to the new key even if the device was originally having the app signed with the old key.

Comment: `> Why isn’t rotation with v3 or v3.1 supported for Play Store APK uploads?`

Android App Bundle has replaced APK as the standard publishing format in Google Play ([ref](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html)).

Comment: @KhaledHelmy We're hitting a problem with *Managed* Google Play where a new customer can't upload a version of our APK signed with our old (1024-bit) key, nor with rotation to a new 4096-bit key. Both report that the APK is signed with an insecure key. This is a new application ID suffix of our normal application ID, so I think we can sign with the new key alone for this customer, but we have other customers who already have the 1024-bit signing. Will Google Play block them from uploading a new version?